# editing timestamp on google doc through javascript

Tags: javascript, google-docs

I've created this piece of code to automatically update timestamp whenever a person in my group opens up a GoogleDoc

```
function onOpen() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var userName = Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy")
  var body = doc.getBody();

  switch (userName){
    case "xxx@gmail.com":
      body.replaceText("xxx.*$", "xxx" + date);
      break;
    case "yyy@gmail.com":
      body.replaceText("yyy.*$", "yyy" + date);
      break;       
    case "zzz@@gmail.com":
      body.replaceText("zzz.*$", "zzz" + date);
      break;

  }
}
```

but i can't quite run the code i'm using xxx as my own address but it won't overwrite the xxx string inside the doc and i can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `userName` variable is not correctly set. 
You should replace :

```
var userName = Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())
```

By :

```
var userName = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
```

May I suggest you one improvement and maybe another alternative solution ?

***Improvement:***
Extract login of user (xxx, yyy...) from email, and then avoid use of switch instruction. It will ensure evolution with new users without changing code.

***Alternative solution:***
[Drive audit log, and Activity dashboard](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4579696)
(of course, only if you are a GSuite Business user)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and solution, your solution works nicely. I don't plan on scaling this to more then 5 users which are people i expect to participate